# SSIS Power Query Data Source Web API extract error when deployed to server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, get, powerquery

I'm working on extracting data from a https get api. I am using the [Power Query source in SSIS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100619) (SQL Server 2017 and SSDT 2017)

Everything works fine when I run the package locally. When I deploy and run the package on the server I get the following error:

> Error: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

I'm able run the package on the server with a C# extract with no issue. I would like to move away from the script task as the Power Query source is much faster.

Suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by using a Service Account that has sysadmin on the SSIS server. I believe this has something to do with the API using https.